# Highchart with Range selector for SQL Data in html website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

i want to add a range selector in my Chart, but i don´t know how to do it. i´ve tried some example from jsfiddle , but it´s not working.

Here is my code:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="65;url=http://localhost/23-1_chart.php"/>
<title>XXX</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/XXX.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="chart" style="height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script>
$(function() {
//Highcharts with mySQL and PHP - Ajax101.com

var Voc_value = [];
var time = [];
var switch1 = true;
$.get('23-1_values.php', function(data) {

data = data.split('/');
for (var i in data) {
if (switch1 == true) {
time.push(data[i]);   
switch1 = false;
} else {
  Voc_value.push(parseFloat(data[i]));
  switch1 = true;
}

}
time.pop();  // cursor

$('#chart').highcharts({
chart : {
type : 'spline'
},
title : {
  text : 'VOC-Value-A.ROOM'
},
subtitle : {
  text : 'Room A'
},
xAxis : {
 title : {
 text : 'time'
 },
categories : time
 },
yAxis : {
title : {
text : 'VOC-value in ppm'
},
labels : {
  formatter : function() {
    return this.value + 'VOCvalue'
  }
 }
},
tooltip : {
crosshairs : true,
shared : true,
valueSuffix : 'ppm'
},
plotOptions : {
spline : {
marker : {
radius : 4,
lineColor : '#666666',
lineWidth : 1
}
}
},
series : [{

name : 'VOC-value in ppm',
data : Voc_value
}]
});
});
});</script>
```

First i read the sql values and put it in 23-1_values.php. 
My sql values are  reading from this php-page 23.1_values.php and then the chart is build. I have the datetime (day-hour-min-s) in the abscissae axis and the ppm value in the ordinate axis
I´m getting too much values and want to reduce the dateformat and add a range selector in the chart.

How can i do it?

Thanks

Comment: The rangeselector is available only in highstock and for datetime data. In your case you have categories. So you need to transofrm your data into correct format and use highstock.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for your answer. What do you mean by transform into correct format?

Comment: I mean not use categoires, by time in miliseconds and set type of xAxis as datime. If you have not this form, you should use loops / condition and i.e Date.parse / Date.UTC() to create corret format of data.

Comment: I can only have the form "categories", because time is reading from another page.

Comment: I Bochan, i change the date format and now have a blank page: no chart, no graph. Here is the code:

Comment: Do you receve an error in the console? Because data looks like correct, do you use webserver to load data?

Comment: no. i receive no error. it´s only blank. i use internet explorer

Comment: I mean, if your files are on webserver or you open it from local file system?

Comment: i open my file from local file system (localhost/.../....php)

Comment: Look at your console (dev tools in the browser) and check if this not block loading files from your location

Comment: you are right: in the console, i have an error:"undefine highchart" from this line $('#container').highcharts('StockChart',... But how must i define it?

Comment: It means that you don't load highcharts.js anywhere

Comment: I add the Highchart library at the bottom. But i have a new error from the same line  as before:"The object does not support property or method highcharts".

Comment: You try to load highcharts before highcharts.js. Run in this order: jquery / highcharts.js / yourhighchartsscript.js

Comment: I´m run it this way as you saiy:<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>. But i´m still getting an error:The object doesn't support this action .

Comment: Looks correct, have you live demo  ?

Comment: The page is still blank. I only have this error in the console of the IE dev tools.

Comment: After some changes i´ve got a chart. But still having an error: SCRIPT5007 : Object expected.. What type of error is that.

Comment: Without live example Im not able to investigate it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

i don´t really know what i have done, but it is working now. Thank you very much for helping me.Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>XXXXXXXXX</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON("XXX.php", function(data) {

    // Create a timer
    var start = + new Date();

    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            events: {
                load: function(chart) {
                    this.setTitle(null, {
                        text: 'Built chart at '+ (new Date() - start) +'ms'
                    });
                }
            },
            zoomType: 'x'
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                type: 'day',
                count: 1,
                text: '24h'
            }, {
                type: 'week',
                count: 1,
                text: '1w'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1m'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 6,
                text: '6m'
            }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: '1y'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            selected: 0
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'XX'
            }
        },

        title: {
            text: 'XX'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Built chart at...' // dummy text to reserve space for dynamic subtitle
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'XX',
            type: 'area',
            data: data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 1,
                valueSuffix: ' ppm'
            },
            fillColor : {
                linearGradient : {
                    x1: 0,
                    y1: 0,
                    x2: 0,
                    y2: 1
                },
                stops : [[0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]], [1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)']]
            },
        }/*,
        {
            name: 'Temperatur',
            type: 'area',
            data: datarasp,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 1,
                valueSuffix: ' °C'
            },
            fillColor : {
                linearGradient : {
                    x1: 0,
                    y1: 0,
                    x2: 0,
                    y2: 1
                },
                stops : [[0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]], [1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)']]
            },
        }*/]

     });
     });
   });
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>


   <div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Hope it will help someone